# Best way to listen to the changes of one user on another users account, without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress, dom-events

I'm creating a system that has a game like structure. The changes of the users are updating data in the database using aJax. It's easy to alter the DOM with data using such a method ... but what if I want to updating from one users activity, and have it show on the other users screen?
a continual timeout function seems like it might slow the system down. Is there a better way?

Comment: You need dome kind of message queue / message broker / event bridge. The technologies you listed are not really suitable for such things as you can only regularly poll mysql for changes, which does not scale. You need a proper backend like redis, firebase or rabbitmq, and websockets to keep in touch with the clients. Alternative is to use messaging services provided by one of the big cloud providers.

Comment: what about event listening? is it possible to listen to an event triggered by another user?

Comment: That's what I described above.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: referring to JavaScript's event listeners.

Comment: I think you may be looking for this: https://wptavern.com/how-to-take-control-of-the-wordpress-heartbeat-api

Comment: The js event listeners will not help you with cross-client events.

Comment: So a cross-client event is one that bypasses the server. What if we did client event > server > other client listener
Would that need a cron job?